# I want the minimum to be 0 but the substraction is still negative

Tags: php

I'm beggining in OOP with PHP, and i want to make 2 opponent fight, with the function fight. I want to have a $degat variable which is a result of a radom number between 1 to strength of attacker - (minus) dexterity of defender.
So  the result must be of minimum 0.

I have this code and when I var_dump it I still have negative value. I can't see what i'm doing wrong.

```
public function fight(Fighter $target)
{

    // $degat = (rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity) >= 0 ? (rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity) : 0;
    if ((rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity) > 0) {
        $degat = (rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity);
    } else {
        $degat = 0;
    };

    var_dump($degat);

    $target->life -= $degat;
}
```

thanks !

Comment: Do you expect the return value of `rand()` to be deterministic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the result of `rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity)` in a variable, you could also omit the if-statement completely and reduce your method to:

```php
public function fight(Fighter $target)
{
    // max(a,b) returns the higher number from a and b
    $target->life -= max(0, rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem here is the fact that each time you call rand, the result is different. So, you should save the expression with rand and then reuse it.

Also, the whole thing could be done slightly shorter with the use of ternary operator.

```
$expr = (rand(1, $this->strength) - $target->dexterity);

$degat = $expr > 0 ? $expr : 0
```

Some notes:

- `rand` does not generate cryptographically secure values and could also depend on the staring seed, you could also consider using `random_int`, I think it helps randomizing your game, for sure
- read more about ternary operator here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Awsome answer thanks a lot ! Thanks for all the details.

Comment: @trueChoan if the answer has solved the problem, could you click a checkmark, please?